# COPY command limitation in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, copy, cqlsh

When I execute this command on MAC OS I got file created -

> (01:53 PM)[v0zilbe@L-SB8T2SCG3Q-M]: ~$ cqlsh --cqlversion=3.2.1 
>   Connected to MCSE_CLUSTER at 172.16.117.212:9042. [cqlsh 5.0.1 |
>   Cassandra 2.1.12.1046 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3] Use HELP
>   for help. cqlsh:> copy a to 'a.csv'; Using 7 child processes
>
> Starting copy of a with columns ['key', 'column1', 'value'].
>   Processed: 52033 rows; Rate:      59 rows/s; Avg. rate:     138 rows/s
>   52033 rows exported to 1 files in 6 minutes and 16.173 seconds. cqlsh>

However the same thing done on Linux I got that.

> cqlsh:> copy a to 'a.csv'; list size out of the sanity limit (10000
>   items max) cqlsh:>

The Linux is CentOS release 6.9

Comment: What is your table schema ?

Comment: Key string, column1 string, value string.

Comment: May be your string is very large

Comment: Maybe. But the same command works on Mac OS.